# Is there a functionality in .NET through which a method can determine which class has call it

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, oop, frameworks

I have a class in which there is a method and i have some aspx pages which call this method. Now I want to know in this method which page has call it. 
OR
Is there a functionality in .NET through which a method can determine which class has call it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
        System.Diagnostics.StackFrame f = new System.Diagnostics.StackFrame();
        Type t = f.GetMethod().DeclaringType;
        string name = t.FullName;
        string classname = name.Substring((name.IndexOf('.')+1));
```

source is [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxbcl/thread/1e3c0212-6e31-4181-8f3e-a85310c9cf03)

Answer (score 3):

Yuck.

Well anyway,

```
 new StackTrace().GetFrame(1).GetMethod().DeclaringType
```

That will give you the type.

Any reason this is really required? Seems like a spaghetti solution.

Comment: you are right I have a helper method of some kind, and I wants to know what page called the method.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use an interface?
This way you can also limit the Pages that can use the method.

```
interface INamedPage {
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Here's your page:

```
public PageOne: Page, INamedPage {
    ...
    public string Name {
        get { return "Page One"; }
    } 
    ...
}
```

The method that is being called:

```
public void WhoIsIt (INamedPage page) {
   return "Oh it was " + page.Name + " again!";
}
```

Above is a simple example. I wouldn't use strings for all of it. Your solution will have to depend on what you want to do with the Page that called it.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. This should tell you the full url of the page that requested the current one.

```
Request.Urlreferrer
```

Comment: It seems he has a helper method of some kind, and he wants to know what page called the method. Either that or he totally explained it wrong O_o

Comment: Yeah. I'm trying my best to decipher the question. Especially given that classes don't actually call methods. Methods on objects do.